# custom item apparition in beamer

Tags: beamer, itemize

I'm using a beamer template and want to display the different items progressively. My code is the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{summary}

\begin{enumerate}[<+- | alert@+>]

\item Part 1
\begin{itemize}
\item sub1
\item sub2
\item sub3
\end{itemize}

\item Part 2
\begin{itemize}
\item sub1
\item sub2
\item sub3
\end{itemize}

\end{enumerate}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

As you can see I use items within enumerations. My question is: how do I make my items appear at the same time as the enumeration they're in ? In my example, how do I make sub1, sub2 and sub3 appear in the same slide that display Part 1 for the first time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the slide you want each respective item to display on, giving you control over the sequence of display. For this, provide an overlay specification for every `\item`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{summary}

\begin{enumerate}

  \item<1-4> Part 1
    \begin{itemize}
      \item<2-4> sub1
      \item<2-4> sub2
      \item<2-4> sub3
    \end{itemize}

  \item<3-4> Part 2
    \begin{itemize}
      \item<4> sub1
      \item<4> sub2
      \item<4> sub3
    \end{itemize}

\end{enumerate}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```